# What kind of colors blend to make the forecolor distinct from the backcolor?

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, blending, color-blending

Suppose I know the backcolor and I want to change the forecolor accordingly to make the text distinct from the background. For example, if the current text color (forecolor) is RED, for some change of user, the backcolor also becomes RED or close to RED (which will make the text illegible), in such a case, I want to change the forecolor using some colors blending formula to make it distinct from the backcolor and maintain the legibility.

Hope you can help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information on [this blog entry](http://24ways.org/2010/calculating-color-contrast/), I could come up with the following C# code, that returns either `Color.Black` or `Color.White` for the best contrast with the given (background) color:

```
public Color GetContrastingColor(Color backColor)
{
    int r = (int)backColor.R;
    int g = (int)backColor.G;
    int b = (int)backColor.B;

    int yiqSpace = ((r * 299) + (g * 587) + (b * 114)) / 1000;

    if (yiqSpace > 131)
    {
        return Color.Black;
    }
    else
    {
        return Color.White;
    }
}
```

The method uses [YIQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YIQ) to determine if a color is considered light or dark, and returns a constrasting color in return.

Comment: Black or White is so ugly to me, I rarely use Black or white for my control texts. Sorry

Comment: You are free to return different colors or think of your own method. I'm just showing you a way to achieve this.

Comment: Your answer just lets me know about YIQ, as I understand this can help me choose only 1 from 2 predefined colors, well this is worth trying, thanks.